# Prompted for Confirm Form Resubmission on refreshes after postback. What am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, postback

I have a dashboard which starts in a blank/default state. I am giving the user the ability to load a saved state into the dashboard. When they click the 'Apply' button I run the following code:

```
function CloseAndSave() {
    var radUpload = $find(radUpload1ID);
    var inputs = radUpload.getFileInputs();

    if (inputs[0].value.length == 0) {
        alert('Please select a dashboard to upload.');
        return;
    }

    if( !radUpload.isExtensionValid(inputs[0].value) ) {
        alert('Please select an XML file.');
        radUpload.clearFileInputAt(0);
        return;
    }

    oWindow = null;
    __doPostBack(radButton1ID);
}

protected void RadButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        UploadedFile dashboardXMLFile = RadUpload1.UploadedFiles[0];

        SerializableDictionary<string, string> dataToLoad = new SerializableDictionary<string, string>();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToLoad.GetType());

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dashboardXMLFile.InputStream))
        {
            dataToLoad = (SerializableDictionary<string, string>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        foreach (var entry in dataToLoad)
        {
            string sessionKey = entry.Key;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Value))
            {
                Type type = StateManager.GetTypeFromStateName(sessionKey);

                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(entry.Value);
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
                    SessionRepository.Instance.SetSession(sessionKey, xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RadButton1 has the property "AutoPostBack" set to false. I have set AutoPostBack to false because I wanted to perform validation before running the click event. So, now, I perform client-side validation and then allow the button click to run.

There's no update panel wrapping RadButton1. As such, the whole page posts after RadButton1_Click. This causes the state of the page to 'load up' the parsed state.

At this point, if I refresh the page, Google Chrome says "Please confirm form resubmission." I've read about how to squelch this, but I'd rather track down root cause.

Solution:

```
//This changes the response to a GET instead of a POST. Prevents the 'Form Resubmission' dialog.
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: Any time a page is submitted by a form POST, refreshing the page with the browser button (F5 or whatever) will (should) prompt you. That's normal behavior. You have to squelch it because the root cause is ordinary browser behavior that is meant to prevent accidental re-submission of forms that actually DO something such as submit a payment.

Comment: I think that if this data resubmits silently bad things will happen. I need to find a way to clear the POST data after it occurs. I am reading about PRG currently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you refresh the browser, it will resend the last request you did. If it was a POST request (like you do in case of postback) then it will re-post the information but before doing it you'll see the warning message you describe.

The best way to avoid this problem is implementing the pattern [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a common design pattern for web developers to help avoid certain duplicate form submissions and allow user agents to behave more intuitively with bookmarks and the refresh button.

Normally people don't implement this (although we should) unless the re-post may cause some data inconsistency.

Comment: Hey, so I did some reading about this, and I am confused on how to implement it. Do you know of any ASP.NET AJAX examples of this? I did a bit of Googling, but most of the talk is conceptual. I was thinking of going into the PageRequestManager's OnResponseEnd event and redirecting to the page when it detects the proper conditions. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: I marked this as an answer for the valuable information that you provided, but I have moved the discussion to a new post in an attempt to get some more info. Thank you!

Comment: @Sean Anderson: I'm a little confused. I probably didn't get very well your idea. You said that RadButton1 submitted the whole page without using AJAX. So not sure why you try to involve PageRequestManager if the request is not involving any ajax interaction.

Comment: Hey, I was a little confused, too. :) I ended up not going this route at all. What I did was at the end of the RadButton1_Click event I put "            Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);" which causes the page to reload after the event finishes -- changing it to a get instead of a post.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the browser, it will resend the last request you did. If it was a POST request (like you do in case of postback) then it will re-post the information but before doing it you'll see the warning message you describe.