# Previous Page Asp.net c# error : Confirm Form Resubmission

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, http, response

I need to return on my previous page with a button, I found lot of solution ( c# and js) but everytime I have the same problem : The action is the same as the click of the previous navigator button so same problem because I used form on my second page so when I click on my previous button I have a page with this message : "Confirm Form Resubmission" and "Err_Cache_Miss"

I used this code : 
On my page_load :

```
  if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {

            ViewState["UrlReferent"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        }
```

And on my previous button :

```
Response.Redirect((String)ViewState["UrlReferent"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request.RawUrl instead of ViewState

Comment: Thank you but Request.rawUrl return the url of the current page and I need to go back on the previous page

Comment: <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnRequest_OnLick"/>

That's my html button with runat.
protected void btnRequest_OnLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect((String)ViewState["UrlReferent"]);
        }

And this is my click in .cs and it's totaly worked for me. May be your viewstate will crush cause of timeout

Comment: It worked for me if I don't submit my form when I'm in the second page. If I submit my form ( for add a user in my database for exemple ) the button refresh the page or display a white page with "Confirm Form Resubmission"

Comment: [Refresh after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352928/prompted-for-confirm-form-resubmission-on-refreshes-after-postback-what-am-i-do)

You can read this

Comment: It's exactly my problem ! Do you know the solution in my case because I tried this : Page.Response.Redirect((String)ViewState["UrlReferent"], true); but it doesn't work

Comment: I found the problem, actions on my form refresh my page so my previous url change and I have not solutions...